# Ubuntu / i3wm: rename AppImage in dmenu entry

Tags: ubuntu, i3, dmenu, appimage

I downloaded an AppImage (LogSeq to be precise) and wanted to add it to the dmenu.

With the help of a friend i did the following:

1. move AppImage to a appropriate directory (not required, but appears cleaner to me).

   In this case i moved the `LogSeq.AppImage` to `/home/[username]/.local/bin/LogSeq.AppImage`
2. Create a `.desktop` entry with the required fields in `/usr/share/applications` -> `logseq.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=LogSeq
GenericName=logseq
Exec=/home/[username]/.local/bin/LoqSeq.AppImage
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application;
```

After removing `~/.cache/dmenu_run` to have dmenu rebuild it's cache, the app appears in the dmenu and i can run it. Cool!

However both in `dmenu_run` as well as in the **dmenu** itself, the app appears as `LogSeq.AppImage` not as `logseq` as i had expected.

How can i rename it so that it appears e.g. as `logseq` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications`.

`dmenu` looks for executables in your path, so you can make a symlink called `logseq` that points to the path of your LogSeq.Appimage.